Annotate JSON schema properties in Python with msgspec (or pydantic)
In the JSON schema produced from a msgspec Struct, I'm wanting to output to the schema some text descriptions of the properties held within the Struct in the same way as the docstring of the Struct shows up in the JSON schema.
This little toy example (cut down from https://jcristharif.com/msgspec/jsonschema.html):
import json
import msgspec
from msgspec import Struct

def print_schema(schema):
    encoded_schema = msgspec.json.encode(schema)
    formatted_schema = json.dumps(json.loads(encoded_schema), indent=4)
    print(formatted_schema)

class Product(Struct):
    """A product in a catalog"""
    id: int
    name: str
    price: float

schema = msgspec.json.schema(Product)
print_schema(schema)

outputs:
{
    "$ref": "#/$defs/Product",
    "$defs": {
        "Product": {
            "title": "Product",
            "description": "A product in a catalog",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "price": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "id",
                "name",
                "price"
            ]
        }
    }
}

with description containing the docstring. I'd like to do something like
class Product(Struct):
    """A product in a catalog"""
    id: int      # DB uid
    name: str    # Name of product
    price: float # Price of product

and have the comments show up in the JSON schema against the appropriate property. Perhaps something like:
{
    "$ref": "#/$defs/Product",
    "$defs": {
        "Product": {
            "title": "Product",
            "description": "A product in a catalog",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "description": "DB uid"
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "name": {
                    "description": "Name of product"
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "price": {
                    "description": "Price of product"
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "id",
                "name",
                "price"
            ]
        }
    }
}

However, I don't know enough about JSON schemas to know if this is correct or valid although looking at https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step it seems about right.
How can I do this using msgspec? Or maybe rewrite my code to use pydantic? Thanks.

Could you please provide the exact output you'd like to get?

Done. See latest question edit.

With the confidence from the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/78703875/2746401, I had a dig around and found out how to do this with msgspec
from typing import Annotated
import json
import msgspec
from msgspec import Meta, Struct

def print_schema(schema):
    encoded_schema = msgspec.json.encode(schema)
    formatted_schema = json.dumps(json.loads(encoded_schema), indent=4)
    print(formatted_schema)


class Product(Struct):
    """A product in a catalog"""
    id: Annotated[int, Meta(description="DB uid")]
    name: Annotated[str, Meta(description="Name of product")]
    price: Annotated[float, Meta(description="Price of product")]

schema = msgspec.json.schema(Product)
print_schema(schema)


Does this look like what you are looking for?
import json

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Product(BaseModel):
    """A product in a catalog"""

    id: int = Field(description="DB uid")
    name: str = Field(description="Name of product")
    price: float = Field(description="Price of product")


product_schema = Product.model_json_schema()
json_product_schema = json.dumps(product_schema, indent=2)

